# requesting app secure boot virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, multi-boot, emulation, secure-boot

I am wondering if there are any secure programs I could use like virtual machine that can run on boot so I dont have to have a whole os running in the back ground but I am interested in trying different os implementations such as the androidx86 and different versions of linux.... I have made a bootable drive with yumi but this still leaves my main drive accessable to the os and would like to keep the virtual machine locked into a speciffic section of the external. Not wanting to have absolute inability to save as in the tails os.But would also like to see protection from malicious software from corrupting my main drive. Also note I have an old single core system that can only use 2gb ram so a ramdisk is not feasible.I do not need any kind of complete list of software possible,just a recomendation  if such software does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me you want a virtual machine without a virtual machine.  If an OS is running on your computer, it will see your main hard drive, whether or not it can do anything with it.  You don't need much memory for the actual virtual machines.  I have run all kinds of Os's at 750megs ram.

## A1.  Simply use virtual box.

Desktops don't always make for the best hypervisors (make virtual machines) as they are running all kinds of useless things.  Strip down the useless services on your main OS as much as possible.

> Memory. Depending on what guest operating systems you want to run, you will need at least 512 MB of RAM (but probably more, and the more the better). Basically, you will need whatever your host operating system needs to run comfortably, plus the amount that the guest operating system needs. So, if you want to run Windows 8.1 on Windows 7, you probably won't enjoy the experience much with less than 2 GB of RAM.

[Virtual Box documentation.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/End-user_documentation)

## A2.  Install another OS, such as Linux (or a slimmed down windows) as a hypervisor on a secondary hard drive.

We are just talking about the md5 install and update, no malware.  It can "see" your hard drive, but you don't install anything on it.  It is just your hypervisor (Makes virtual machines).  Then from the linux os on the second hard drive, install virtual machines.  Those new virtual machines can simply be in files in that secondary hard drive, or another partition, or another hard drive.

Comment: yes this has been about my experience...I have been teying to run on vista which hogs up about 1gb just launching...will look into linux distros that may be suitable,but have had some issues in the past with them not liking my hardware...

Comment: Mint might be a good choice then to ensure compatibility.  There is a very big ubuntu / mint user group community also.  I have no hardware issues at all.  You can check with this list but outside of Nvidia, drivers aren't much of an issue.  Definitely the last 3-4 years is not the same as earlier.  More of an issue for me with Windows by far honestly.  http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/

Comment: Windows 7 is my preference for a clean dedicated windows desktop that I can "de-crappify" by taking out the native bloatware.  Pardon the french.

Comment: thanks...been concidering the upgrade but for the price....will likely need to get a new system soon anyways..then I get the joys of uefi....this system has had its biggest trouble in the network card because it has some custom pushbutton toggle that needs software support....and when trying ubuntu I had the os stop launching after about a week on a so called stable version....I think it was 12....but I had like 30gb of programs id downloaded on it for it to dump on me....

Comment: Price: I know about 8 operationg systems.  Only one that costs money is Windows.    Stable: If you are experimenting, BSD is excellent for both stability and security.  Compatibility: Once *nix drivers are made, they are made.  It's not much of an issue. Microsoft has been know to "expire" features .  Can't say much about that Ubuntu bug.  I run fedora/RHEL.  Ubuntu is a bit more rock&roll.  Windows update has shutdown more computers than anything in my experience. I won't get into forced upgrades or "sleep of death".. http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/06/03/windows_10_upgrade_satellite_link/